# Identify Values in One Column that are Next to a blank cell

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have two columns with data, and I'm wanting to identify and have a formula populate column C with all the values in column B that are next to a blank cell in column A.

So column C will start with "NY-ELA.PK.SL.1", since that is the first value that is next to a blank cell.

```
| **equivalent_ccss_standard**| **standard_long_ref** | **Unused_NY_refs**  |   
|-----------------------------|-------------------|-----------------|
| CCSS.ELA-Literacy.CCRA.SL.1 | NY-ELA.A.SL.1     |                 |
| CCSS.ELA-Literacy.CCRA.SL.2 | NY-ELA.A.SL.2     |                 |   
| CCSS.ELA-Literacy.CCRA.SL.3 | NY-ELA.A.SL.3     |                 |   
| CCSS.ELA-Literacy.CCRA.SL.4 | NY-ELA.A.SL.4     |                 |   
| CCSS.ELA-Literacy.CCRA.SL.5 | NY-ELA.A.SL.5     |                 |   
| CCSS.ELA-Literacy.CCRA.SL.6 | NY-ELA.A.SL.6     |                 |   
|                             | NY-ELA.PK.SL.1    |                 |  
|                             | NY-ELA.PK.SL.1.a  |                 |
```

[Here's the sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dHHnlNKz3xtgzyRXdKCNjoz4RNb9bcDSwZKhkbfYOXw/edit#gid=73337225).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=filter(B:B,not(A:A))
```